# Draw icons on all tabs except the first one?

Tags: c#, .net

I am drawing little x's on a tab control so they can be closed.

I don't want to close the first tab, so I don't want to draw the x on the first tab.

How can I make it ignore the first tab?

```
var tabPage = this.tabBrowser.TabPages[e.Index];
var tabRect = this.tabBrowser.GetTabRect(e.Index);
tabRect.Inflate(-2, -2);

var closeImage = Properties.Resources.closeicon;
e.Graphics.DrawImage(closeImage, (tabRect.Right - closeImage.Width), tabRect.Top + (tabRect.Height - closeImage.Height) / 2);
TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, tabPage.Text, tabPage.Font, tabRect, tabPage.ForeColor, TextFormatFlags.Left);
```

I did try checking how many tabs existed with `tabBrowser.Count` but this ends up drawing on the first tab when there is more than one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't want to close the first tab, so I don't want to draw the x on
>   the first tab.

?...just check for `e.Index > 0` like this:

```
    private void tabBrowser_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
    {
        // always draw the tab text:
        TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, tabPage.Text, tabPage.Font, tabRect, tabPage.ForeColor, TextFormatFlags.Left);

        // only draw the X if we are not the first tab:
        if (e.Index > 0)
        {
            var tabPage = this.tabBrowser.TabPages[e.Index];
            var tabRect = this.tabBrowser.GetTabRect(e.Index);
            tabRect.Inflate(-2, -2);

            var closeImage = Properties.Resources.closeicon;
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(closeImage, (tabRect.Right - closeImage.Width), tabRect.Top + (tabRect.Height - closeImage.Height) / 2);       
        }     
    }
```

Comment: I honestly knew it would be as simple as that, spent too long staring at the screen yesterday.